# Content scrolls down when focusing on Input field with keyboard type "default" in Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a `ScrollView` component, and within it I have a form (`<AppForm >`) that works using [Formik](https://formik.org/) and [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup#install). This form has some input fields (`<AppTextInput >`). In the form I assign the `keyboardType` prop for each input field.

The problem is that the fields with `keyboardType` set to `default` scroll down the whole `ScrollView` component when you focus on it, like adding margin to the top of it. This only happens when the `keyboardType` is set to `default`.

If I focus on an input field with the `keyboardType` prop set to `numeric`, everything works fine.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Here is a gif of what's exactly the problem:

https://giphy.com/gifs/djoHUBAKu9XGyu37OO

And here is my code:

AppFormField (Main screen)

```
function ActivityFormScreen({ navigation }) {

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ActivityIndicator
        visible={
          postActivityApi.loading ||
          editActivityApi.loading ||
          getTrabajosApi.loading ||
          getCosechasApi.loading ||
          getMaquinariasApi.loading
        }
      />
      <ScrollView style={{ paddingBottom: 500 }}>
        <ActivityTitle
          text="Información"
          name="information-variant"
          size={35}
        />
        <AppForm
          onSubmit={(form) => handleSubmit(form)}
          validationSchema={validationShema}
          initialValues={{
            fecha: getFormValue("fecha"),
            finca_id: getFormValue("finca_id"),
            lote: getFormValue("lote"),
            cosecha: getFormValue("cosecha"),
            cultivos: getFormValue("cultivos"),
            maquinaria: getFormValue("maquinaria"),
            tiempo_actividad: getFormValue("tiempo_actividad"),
            productos: getFormValue("productos"),
            cantidad: getFormValue("cantidad"),
            unidad: getFormValue("unidad"),
            hectarea_trabajada: getFormValue("hectarea_trabajada"),
            trabajos: getFormValue("trabajos"),
            observaciones: getFormValue("observaciones"),
          }}
        >
          <AppFormField
            name="fecha"
            holder="Fecha"
            keyboardType="default"
            placeholder="AAAA-MM-DD"
            defaultValue={getFormValue("fecha")}
          />
          <AppPickerField
            name="finca_id"
            holder="Granja"
            data={context.allFarms} //Seleccionar el array de granjas
            pickerPlaceholder="Seleccione una granja"
            value={getFormValue("finca_id")}
          />
          <AppFormField
            name="lote"
            holder="Lote"
            keyboardType="numeric"
            defaultValue={getFormValue("lote")}
          />
          .
          .
          .
          <SubmitButton title="Guardar" />
        </AppForm>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    // paddingTop: 50,
  },
});
```

AppFormField

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

import AppTextInput from "../AppTextInput";
import ErrorMessage from "./ErrorMessage";

function AppFormField({ placeholder, name, width, holder, ...otherProps }) {
  const { setFieldTouched, handleChange, errors, touched } = useFormikContext();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AppTextInput
        onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
        onChangeText={handleChange(name)}
        width={width}
        holder={holder}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        {...otherProps}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
});

export default AppFormField;
```

AppTextInput

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text, Keyboard } from "react-native";

function AppTextInput({ placeholder = " ", holder, ...otherProps }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.holder}>{holder}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        returnKeyLabel="Listo"
        returnKeyType="done"
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
        {...otherProps}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  holder: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "left",
    color: "#000",
    opacity: 0.6,
    width: "100%",
    height: 30,
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#D9D5DC",
    width: "100%",
  },
});

export default AppTextInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

For some reason my `ScrollView` component had the property `paddingBottom` set to 500, and just by removing it, I solved the issue.